# Load Tensorflow Model and reuse it by the another functions

Tags: tensorflow

I have to load model in initialization and then reuse it by some function. In my architecture function run predict on several datasets by one model and I thought that load model from hard drive for each dataset is not a good solution.

I need something like this, that sharing session (or model) between functions:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.graph = tf.Graph()
    with self.graph.as_default():
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        with sess.as_default():
           saver.restore(tf.get_default_session(), path_to_checkpoint)

def some_func():
    with self.graph.as_default():
        with self.sess.as_default():
            self.sess.run()
```

Is there any proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define model architecture and load its weights as a class. Use it for various datasets in different functions.

```
class vgg16:
def __init__(self, imgs, weights=None, sess=None):
    self.imgs = imgs
    self.convlayers()
    self.fc_layers()
    self.probs = tf.nn.softmax(self.fc3l)
    if weights is not None and sess is not None:
        self.load_weights(weights, sess)

def convlayers(self):
    self.parameters = []
      ::
      ::

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sess = tf.Session()
    imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 224, 224, 3])
    vgg = vgg16(imgs, 'vgg16_weights.npz', sess)

    # run inference here on multiple datasets
```

Check here : https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frossard/vgg16/vgg16.py

Does that helps you ?